# Magento 2.0 Catalog Product table list view

Tags: magento2

[image]

I have a error in product catalog table grid header is not working properly. Kindly share your answers.

this error only comes in aws server online only. the same file i will use in local this error not appear.
Thank You..

Comment: this error only comes in aws server online only. the same file i will use in local this error not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fix this issue,

just add the below code your **.htaccess file**

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module> ModPagespeed off </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove all folder from `pub/static` path.

Run deploy command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Remove **var** folder from root.

**clear browser cache**

Check again for page.

Comment: Thank you rakesh but this not work for me.. any other options for you..